# setBitmap for analog clock in app widget doesn't work android

Tags: java, android

I'm going to change background of analog clock in app widget and I have to use bitmap for some reasons.
but this code doesn't work for me!
could some body help me please?!Thanks a lot

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FilePathStrings[position]);
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
remoteViews.setBitmap(R.id.analogClock1,"setImageBitmap" ,bitmap);
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, Widget.class);
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
manager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Comment: `code doesn't work for me` which way it doesn't work? crash? doesn't compile? doesn't set image?

Comment: @VladMatvienko the bitmap doesn't set to my analog clock! I tested this code for another views like imageview and it worked fine. the problem is just for analog clock! and on my widget is written "problem loading widget"

Comment: check the logcat. Does it show any strange messages? Any stacktrace?

Comment: @VladMatvienko No! after running setBitmap method, my logcat doesn't show any special log!and that's empty :|

Comment: and you are 100% sure that your bitmap is being loaded to `Bitmap bitmap` correctly, right?

Comment: I really dont khow why should I do! searching for it took me a long time. and it have not solved! :(((

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes i'm sure,as I told you, I tested just this code for an image view and it worked right remoteViews.setBitmap(R.id.imageview,"setImageBitmap" ,bitmap);

Comment: have you tried to load another bitmap? maybe smaller size one?

Comment: @VladMatvienko bitmap correctly loaded to imageview

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes I tried smaller size so! and didnt get any result

Comment: @VladMatvienko I finally solved the problem.I found originally analog clock doesn't have "setBitmap" method. not in activity classes,not in appwidget classes and not anywhere else! exactly like button. but imageview has this method. that's why I couldn't use this method for analog clack.So I had to use a imageview in back of my analog clock and changed it to a circle imageview by using shape in drawable.Then I used "setBitmap" method for that imageview and solved.